# Program execution comparator

Tags: c++, debugging

I often face cases where I could troubleshoot programs by comparing the execution traces of two versions of it, from the same inputs, until the behaviors diverge.

This could probably be done by logging all steps taken (minimally, could be just the visited line numbers; maximally, output of all modified values). And on a second run, break as soon as a change is found.

Comparison with the granularity of high-level languages constructs (lines) could do; assembly-level as well (provided cross referencing the source code is done).

Is there any symbolic debugger or equivalent product able to do that ?

Comment: "tracing line numbers" is likely to be pretty useless if the two programs, of any scale, differed by a single inserted blank line,  (or more likely, by random blank lines, comments, or linebreaks).  You'll have to define what you mean by "Step" more carefully.

Comment: I also suspect that if both programs read nondeterministic values (eg., a random number generator, or a time of day clock), that you'd find the divergence at that point.  This shows you need to define "equivalence of values"; are the variables char x; and int x; equivalent if they are both incremented, and the character overflows?  If the program only cares about the lower 8 bits x, they are.

Comment: @Ira: quite right about line numbers, and more generally it seems obvious that execution traces can diverge only where code is entered. In theory, just the modified lines should be traced then, and "old" line numbers should be preserved (a diff tool can do). The practical issue to be solved is that divergence can only trigger at the Nth passing, where N is huge and unknown.

Comment: @Ira: using this approach on non-deterministic programs (be they randomized or concurrent) makes little sense. Execution traces must be repeatable.

Comment: Yves Daust: Diff is a pretty awful tool for lining up line numbers; you need a smart differencer to track how one relates to the other.  And of course, where they differ, you should expect divergence; otherwise, why would they be different?  Regarding non-determinitic programs: what real programs of scale do you wish to apply this to, that don't have some aspect of this?

Comment: As I said, the usefulness of the tool is to break into the program *when* divergence occurs, not just *where*. Diff is a smart differencer.